# ORA-01843 - not a valid month oracle SQL

Tags: php, sql, oracle

Below I am attempting to pull information from an oracle database. However, I keep getting this error:

```
Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

Why is my code publishing this error? TIA!

Code:

```
$objConnect = oci_connect("user", "password", "(description=(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=host)(port=1533))(connect_data=(service_name=sid)))");
$weekSQL2 =  "SELECT * FROM INTOXDM.LSS_COP WHERE COP_WEEK = to_date('2014-08-06 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')";
$weekParse2 = oci_parse($objConnect, $weekSQL2);  
$weekExecute2 = oci_execute($weekParse2);
$week2 = oci_fetch_all($weekParse2,$week12);
```

**NOTE**

Here is what dates look like in my database:

```
2014-06-23 00:00:00.0
```

Which confuses me even more because my formatting is the exact same as what is in the database.

Comment: What is the type of `COP_WEEK`?  Perhaps that is where you are getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is that `COP_WEEK` column is not defined as **`DATE`**, but some other datatype (e.g. VARCHAR),

For the OP query, Oracle is performing an *implicit* datatype conversion of the values in the `COP_WEEK` column, from `VARCHAR` to `DATE`. The implicit `TO_DATE` conversion is using format as specified in the client `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` variable, likely it's the default `'DD-MON-RR'`. Whatever it is, it doesn't "match" what's stored in the column.

Or, if the NLS_DATE_FORMAT does match most of the values stored in the column, there's at least one that has a COP_WEEK value that doesn't match the format.

---

One code "fix" (I put it in quotes because it's not really the right fix) is to make the conversion explicit, using the TO_DATE function:

```
WHERE TO_DATE(COP_WEEK,'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS') =
```

Another option for a code "fix" would be to compare the bare VARCHAR column to a VARCHAR literal

```
WHERE COP_WEEK = '2014-08-06 00:00:00.0'
```

This has the advantage of allowing Oracle to make use of an index, rather than requiring a conversion  for every row...

---

A better option would be to store COP_WEEK as a DATE datatype, rather than a VARCHAR, but that would be more than a change to your code.

Comment: Since OP has an equality in the WHERE clause, if `COP_WEEK` is a `VARCHAR`, then there is no need to convert anything to a date.  Best option, of course, is to use an actual `DATE` datatype.

Comment: @WW: agreed. I did propose that as a possible code "fix". I went with the explicit TO_DATE conversion first; mostly because that helps _explain_ why the exception is being thrown with the existing query. We'd get the same error with explicit TO_DATE if the supplie format doesn't match at least one value stored in that column.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I just ended changing it from a `DATE` datatype to `VARCHAR` because I was too confused haha